# React hook form: Registering fields within nested arrays while only rendering one child array at a time in form output preview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to go about conditionally rendering nested arrays within an array of data while still registering all fields to the form.

An example of the initial form data / default values:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Section 1",
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "search-bar",
        "placeholder": "Search products...",
        "order": 0,
        "id": "gjdim"
      },
      {
        "type": "banner",
        "image_src": "https://adfasdf.com/abc.jpg",
        "url": null,
        "collections": [],
        "productIds": [8372738],
        "action": "product",
        "destination": "8379948",
        "multiplier": 1.5,
        "id": "dvwef"
      },
      {
        "type": "banner",
            "image_src": "https://adfasdfa.com/abc.jpg",
        "url": null,
        "collections": [],
        "productIds": [],
        "action": "static",
        "destination": null,
        "multiplier": 0.461538,
        "id": "fdvwd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Section 2",
    "blocks": [
      {
        "id": "kjjne",
        "type": "custom",
        "customBlockId": "jviwufs",
        "source": "https://asdfasdf.com/abc/asdf/index.html",
        "multiplier": 1,
        "version": "1.1.0",
        "tags": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Section 3",
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "search-bar",
        "placeholder": "Search products...",
        "order": 0,
        "id": "abcde"
      },
      {
        "type": "single-collection-carousel",
        "collections": [837839],
        "imageFill": true,
        "itemCount": 6,
        "id": "bdcds"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My current logic uses the useFieldArray hook for all parent items in the outer array and within each parent, I'm passing the child array data to the useFieldArray hook. Because I need to conditionally render the child items based on which parent item is selected, I'm struggling to figure out how to cleanly register the whole nested form while returning only the child items of the active/selected parent to output in an AppPreview component.. Very open to suggestions if this is a better way to go about this..

Current Implementation:

```
import React from "react";
import { useController, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";

export default function MultiPages({ control, register }) {
  const { fields: multiPageFields } = useFieldArray({
    name: "multiPages",
    control,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {multiPageFields.map((field, index) => {
        return (
          <Multipage
            multipage={field}
            index={index}
            register={register}
            control={control}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const Multipage = ({ register, control, index }) => {
  const { fields: blocks } = useFieldArray({
    name: `multiPages.${index}.blocks`,
    control,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <input {...register(`multiPages.${index}.name`)} />;
      {blocks.map((block, blockIndex) => {
        return (
          <Block
            multiPageIndex={index}
            blockIndex={blockIndex}
            control={control}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

const Block = ({ multiPageIndex, blockIndex, control, register }) => {
  const {
    field,
    fieldState: { invalid, isTouched, isDirty },
    formState: { touchedFields, dirtyFields },
  } = useController({
    name: `multiPage.${multiPageIndex}.blocks.${blockIndex}`,
    control,
    rules: { required: true },
  });

  console.log("field", field);

  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

The issue with the code above is that, while it's registering all of the multiPage fields and nested blocks, all of the blocks in every multiPage object are being returned/rendered whereas I need to be able to only return the blocks for the actively selected multiPage.

UPDATED IMPLEMENTATION:
Made some adjustments for conditionally rendering a nested array but I still feel like this is a messy way to go about it...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";

export default function MultiPages({ control, register }) {
  const [activeMultiPage, setActiveMultipage] = useState(0);
  const { fields: multiPageFields } = useFieldArray({
    name: "multiPages",
    control,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {multiPageFields.map((field, index) => {
        return (
          <Multipage
            multipage={field}
            index={index}
            register={register}
            control={control}
            activeMultiPage={activeMultiPage}
            setActiveMultipage={setActiveMultipage}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const Multipage = ({
  multipage,
  register,
  control,
  setActiveMultipage,
  activeMultiPage,
  index,
}) => {
  const { fields: blocks } = useFieldArray({
    name: `multiPages.${index}.blocks`,
    control,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    blocks.map((registerBlock, registerBlockIndex) => {
      register(`multiPages.${index}.blocks.${registerBlockIndex}`);
    });
  }, [blocks, index]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setActiveMultipage(index)}>
        {multipage.name}
      </button>
      <input {...register(`multiPages.${index}.name`)} />;
      {activeMultiPage === index &&
        blocks.map((block, blockIndex) => {
          return (
            <Block
              multiPageIndex={index}
              blockIndex={blockIndex}
              control={control}
            />
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

const Block = () => {
  return <div>block</div>;
};
```